# Why I get error stack level too deep when run callback after_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 model:

- GeneralExam has many TopicQuestion
- TopicQuestion belongs to GeneralExam, belongs_to Topic

This is columns in two model:

- GeneralExam: name, description, number_question
- TopicQuestion: general_exam_id, topic_id, number_question

I want to calculate total number of questions of general exam, by plus number_question of each topic in TopicQuestion. So I write a method like this:

```
class GeneralExam < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :topic_questions, dependent: :destroy

  validates :number_question, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }, on: :save

  after_save :calc_number_question

  private

  def calc_number_question
    number_question = 0
    self.topic_questions.each do  |tq|
      number_question += tq.number_question
    end
    self.number_question = number_question
    self.save
  end
end
```

But when I submit, I get error:

```
SystemStackError in GeneralExamsController#create
stack level too deep
```

This is my parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"VyojDMOltc5wOJMDf4gtDM6lEk6soTZl/EaY9qrCRyY=",
 "general_exam"=>{"course_id"=>"1",
 "name"=>"dada",
 "description"=>"dada",
 "semester_id"=>"1",
 "duration"=>"1",
 "topic_questions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false",
 "topic_id"=>"15",
 "number_question"=>"15"},
 "1"=>{"_destroy"=>"false",
 "topic_id"=>"13",
 "number_question"=>"6"},
 "2"=>{"_destroy"=>"false",
 "topic_id"=>"Choose a topic",
 "number_question"=>""},
 "3"=>{"_destroy"=>"false",
 "topic_id"=>"Choose a topic",
 "number_question"=>""},
 "4"=>{"_destroy"=>"false",
 "topic_id"=>"Choose a topic",
 "number_question"=>""}}},
 "commit"=>"Create General exam"}
```

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You called `self.save` at the end. It's starting another `after_save` callback.

If your rails version is 3.2.1 or higher you can use

```
update_column :number_question, number_question
```

to skip callbacks.

**offtopic:**

You can rewrite it

```
number_question = 0
self.topic_questions.each do  |tq|
  number_question += tq.number_question
end
```

as

```
number_question = self.topic_questions.inject(0) { |sum, tq| sum + tq.number_question }
```

Comment: thanks, I found another way to calculate, I use sum method: `number_question = TopicQuestion.sum(:number_question, conditions: { general_exam_id: self.id })`

Comment: `update_column` works in rails 3.1 and up. I just used it to fix a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `after_commit` as the callback. It'll work fine since then it won't loop.